# how do i compile the sshfs file system on a mac?

Tags: c, osx-leopard, sshfs

I downloaded and installed [FUSE for osx package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxfuse/files/osxfuse-2.6.1/osxfuse-2.6.1.dmg/download).

I downloaded [sshfs for mac](https://github.com/downloads/osxfuse/sshfs/SSHFS-2.4.1.pkg) and successfully installed it on my mac running OSX 10.6.8.

However, at some point, I would like to make some changes to sshfs the [source code](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs).

Following is what I tried to build sshfs:

```
git clone https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs.git
cd sshfs
autoconf
chmod +x configure
./configure
configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

I am stuck and not sure how to fix this.  Looking at the git repository there is no find that is install-sh or install.sh

Comment: You ran ./configure; make; sudo make install ? What did the make say when it failed? Usually these things give you some kind of clue as to why the fail. We can't really know what you mean by "no success".

Comment: @CharlieBurns - I have added specific error messages per your request.

Comment: You can see the contents of the ./configure and makefile scripts if you click on the source code link above.

Comment: My big confusion is why sshfs works but can't compile?

Comment: Using an executable and compiling source code are two different things. You probably _can_ compile it, you just need to figure out _how_ to compile. Your command line "make -f Makefile.am" is wrong. To compile you need two commands: "./configure" and "make". To install it you need one command: "sudo make install". Note that many many things can go wrong in any command and to sort these problems out may take some effort. Or they may go smoothly if everything the source needs is installed property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about autotools, but I think you need to run more commands than just `autoconf`.  Try this sequence:

```
aclocal
autoconf
autoheader
automake --foreign --add-missing --copy
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation and everything appeared to go well until "./configure" I get an error message "checking OpenSSH version... 5.6 >= 4.4, disabling NODELAY workaround
./configure: line 3676: syntax error near unexpected token `SSHFS,'
./configure: line 3676: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SSHFS, fuse >= 2.3 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0)'"

Comment: Ok, I am glad you are making progress.  I would consider the current question to be answered, and the new error message your are getting on line 3676 would be a new problem that I don't know about.